# Which expressions $ f(\frac{\pi}2)=0 $ or $\lim_{x\to \frac{\pi}2} f(x)=0 $ is correct for $f(x)=\frac{2\cos x}{4+5\tan x}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, infinity

I have this function

$$      f(x)=\frac{2\cos x}{4+5\tan x}   ,       $$

and I want to calculate the value of the function at $x=\frac{\pi}2$, the result is $\frac{0}{\infty}$; then, which expression should I use?

$$ f(\frac{\pi}2)=0   $$

$$   \lim_{x\to \frac{\pi}2} f(x)=0   $$

Comment: $\tan \left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)\:\mathrm{is\:undefined}$ so use $\lim _{x\to \frac{\pi }{2}}\:f\left(x\right)$

Comment: @islamm  As far as I searched on the internet, the most results were that $\frac{0}{\infty}$ is not indeterminate, but there were some opposite results as well.

Comment: You have to use the 2nd expression, but as $\frac{0}{\infty}$ is undefined, or as @islamm mentioned, $tan(\frac{\pi}{2})$ is undefined, you have to use the L'Hôpital's rule to find the limit. It again goes to zero, but not in an undefined way!

Comment: $f\left(\frac{\pi }{2}\right)$ means substitution $\frac{\pi }{2}$ in the function @sara96

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the function is undefined at $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$. So you can't find the value of $f(\frac{\pi}{2})$.
But, if you are considering the limit,
$$\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{2 \cos x}{4+5 \tan x}.$$
Because $\tan x = \frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$, we get
$$\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{2 \cos x}{\frac{4 \cos x+5 \sin x}{\cos x}}$$
$$ \iff 
\lim_{x \to \frac{\pi}{2}} \frac{2 \cos^2 x}{4 \cos x+5 \sin x} =0.$$

We obtain the value of its limit is $= 0$.

Even the form of its limit is $\frac{0}{\infty}$, the limit goes to $0.$ This is not indeterminate forms.